# What does the rate of convergence in probability imply about the rate of convergence in the mean?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, expectation

Let $\{ X_n \}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n = O_p(a_n)$, with $\{ a_n \}$ a sequence of positive real numbers. That is, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a finite $C_\varepsilon$ and an integer $n_\varepsilon$ such that $P(a_n^{-1} |X_n| > C_\varepsilon) < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge n_\varepsilon$.

Under which conditions can we conclude that $\mathbb{E} (X_n) = O(a_n)$? Does it suffice to add the condition $\mathbb{E} (|X_n|) < \infty$ for all $n$?

I am aware that $X_n = O_p(a_n)$ does not even guarantee $\mathbb{E} (X_n)$ to be finite,
    but from a number of examples I have encountered, it was indeed the case that $\mathbb{E} (X_n) = O(a_n)$.
    It just feels to me as though there should be some general relationship here.

As a simple, concrete example, suppose that $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are iid random variables, each with mean 0
    and variance 1. Let
    $$
  \bar{X}_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i.
 $$
    By the central limit theorem we have that $\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n$ converges (in distribution)
    to the standard normal distribution. Hence,
    $$
  \sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n = O_p(1),
 $$
    which implies that
    $$
  \bar{X}_n^2 = O_p(n^{-1}).
 $$
    It is well-known that
    $$
  \mathbb{E} (\bar{X}_n^2) = \frac{1}{n} = O(n^{-1}).
 $$
Is it pure coincidence that the expectation is of order $O(n^{-1})$ with the same rate $n^{-1}$ as the random quantity $\bar{X}_n^2$?

Comment: What do you mean by $O_p$?

Comment: @user37238 It's defined in the same paragraph. (I had never seen this notation either, but it is clear here.)

Comment: The condition you propose isn't strong enough.  Consider $X_i$ all drawn uniformly from $[0,1]$ and $(a_n)_n$ diverging to infinity.  (This failure is because the $a_n$ are far too loose as constraints.)  It seems (to me) that your condition will need to control $X_n/a_n$.

Comment: @EricTowers, thanks for the reply. In my case I always have $a_n = n^{-k}$, for some constant $k>0$, so that $a_n$ approaches 0 as $n$ goes to infinity. As far as $X_n/a_n$ is concerned, all I can say is that $X_n/a_n = O_p(1)$.

Comment: Basically, the connection between these tail probability bounds and expectations is Chebyshev's inequality: $P(|X|>t) \leq \frac{E[|X|]}{t}$. Or in your notation, the question is about how rapidly $C_\varepsilon$ diverges as $\varepsilon$ goes to zero. If, for example, it diverges at least as fast as $1/\varepsilon$, then the expectation will not even be finite.

Comment: You will need to somehow require $E[|X_n|/a_n]<\infty$. Otherwise I can find variables with $C_\varepsilon=1/\varepsilon$ and then the question is hopeless. The more interesting question is, if you impose this restriction, do you actually get the result? I think you do, because of the strong restriction that $C_\varepsilon$ does not depend on $n$.

Comment: @Ian If you impose the condition $\mathbb{E} (|X_n|/a_n) < \infty$ for all $n$, this directly implies that $\mathbb E (X_n) = O(a_n)$. This follows directly from the definition of big-$O$ --- some definitions of big-$O$ even allow for the expectation to be unbounded for a finite number of $n$ (see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.3924v1.pdf). In many of the examples I have encountered in my work, one can indeed show that $\mathbb{E} (|X_n|/a_n) < \infty$, but it usually involves endless pages of monotonous, laborious (and hopefully unnecessary) algebra.

Comment: @Charleau Actually no, $E(|X_n|/a_n)<\infty$ for all $n$ doesn't imply $E(X_n)=O(a_n)$. Consider $X_n$ which are each constant and equal to $n a_n$.

Comment: @Ian If $X_n = n a_n$ for all $n$, then it is not true that $\mathbb{E} (|X_n|/a_n) < \infty$ for all $n$. In this case $|X_n|/a_n = n$, which is unbounded! As I understand it, saying $\mathbb{E} (|X_n|/a_n) < \infty$ is the same as saying $\mathbb E (X_n) = O(a_n)$ (depending of course on how exactly we define big-$O$).

Comment: @Charleau No, this is a common mistake. The sequence of numbers $b_n=n$ is a sequence of finite numbers, even though the sequence as a whole is unbounded. A similar common mistake is assuming that if $|X|<\infty$ almost surely then $E[|X|]<\infty$.